# laravel on live server - why validation gives an internal server error when a great amount of data is submitted?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm facing a weird problem with my `laravel 5.8` app only in a live server, whenever we submit a great number of characters(about 5000) in a form we're getting

> `internal server error`

I realize that this happens in the validation part, if I remove it (and enter a lot of data), it works perfectly and inserts well in the database, here is my controller code:

```
        public function createAuthor(Request $request)
            {


                request()->validate(
                    [
                        'name' => ['required', 'min:3'],
                        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email'],
                        'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', 'min:8'],
                        'password_confirmation' => ['required'],
                        'acepto' => ['required'],
                        'biography' => ['max:500'],
                        'state_id'  =>  ['required'],
                        "country" => "required_if:state_id,==,33",
                        'image' => ['mimes:jpeg,png,jpg', 'max:500'],
                    ],
```

```
//rest of code inserting data to database....
```

The validation doesn't seem to have any syntax error.

If only a few characters are inserted in the form's inputs, everything works perfectly with the validation.

Also if we check the code out after the internal error I see this:

> [Thu Jun 27 21:31:57.339455 2019] [http:error] [pid 2633339:tid
>   140420960212736] [client 10.80.0.107:62547: Response header name 
>       expires=Fri, 28-Jun-2019 06' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer:

also another simple example could be this simple code:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
        {

            $request->validate(
                [
                    'post_title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
                    ]);

    }
```

My form points to that store function and simply with that is enough to start getting internal server errors only when a lot of characters are presented.

Also I increased the `memory_limit`, `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to 1G, and nothing.

Any idea of how to solve it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validate like this:

```
$rules = ['name' =>'required', 'min:3',
                    'email' => 'required', 'email', 'unique:users,email',
                    'password' => 'required', 'confirmed', 'min:8',
                    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
                    'acepto' => 'required',
                    'biography' => 'max:500',
                    'state_id'  =>  'required',
                    "country" => 'required_if:state_id,==,33',
                    'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg', 'max:500'];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if (!$validator->fails()) {
         }
     else{
   //validation error message
   }
```

Comment: Why? What is different in your code? This might be the right answer, but it would be much more helpful if you describe what you've done, and why you think it solves the problem.

Comment: It works, partially because now when validation fails I use this code: return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput(); to redirect back with error, but I realize that "->withInput();" code is bringing the internal error, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @user2580401 so you're saying ... it doesn't actually work? Your original problem was a 500 internal server error, and now you have ... 500 internal server error?